# if (HttpContext.Current.Session["id"] != null) is returning NULL EXCEPTION

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class, session

I have a mvc project.

### **problem 1 )**

When i start my project in the my visual studio, session_end (in global.asax) starts. is that normal ? i dont open session and close session at the beginning of the project but it works.

### **problem 2)**

The method i have written in my class works when session_end fires. i set it like this. but when i starts my project, session_end fires. anyway, this is not a big problem for me,,,,

BUT

my method has

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["id"] != null)
```

this line. when this line works, the error occurs

NULL REFERENCE EXCEPTION

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in
>   blabla.dll but was not handled in user code Additional information:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

---

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your `HttpContext` or `Current` is `null`.
if you using c#6 you can do this:

```
if (HttpContext?.Current?.Session["id"] != null)
```

or you can check for `null` separately.

Comment: i am not using c# 6 for now. i used null control for all. it work thanks.

do you have any idea that session_end fires when i start the project ?

Comment: What's your .Net version?

Comment: i use .net framework 4.5

Comment: Your project is MVC or WebForm?

Comment: mvc project,,,,

Comment: I was never faced that problem before, so please check [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246649/ASP-NET-Session-End-event-fires-immediately-after) post, maybe it will help you.

Comment: okay, thank you so much. i will check it.